# Only alphabetical chars in WPF text box

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

Hello I have problem I use these code :

```
private void OnlyText(object sender , TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
  Regex regex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
  e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```

XAML

```
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="OnlyText" x:Name="tbSurrname" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Nazwisko" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="81,137,0,0"/>
```

to allow wpf textbox only alphabetical chars but It doesn't works any solutions ?

Comment: So you can't type your own last name in the box?  The world doesn't speak a-z only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Simple fix, change this:

```
e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
```

...to this:

```
e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't see any issue with your regex, I recommend using

```
e.Handled = e.Text.All(ch => char.IsLetter(ch) && ch < 128);
```

`ch < 128` is to ensure that we have only ASCII chars.

Regex is just "too heavy" for such simple task.

I also suggest you setting breakpoint to see what is actual value of `e.Text`.

Comment: Note  you suggest a different thing: in your code, `ch` can be any Unicode letter while OP only allows ASCII letters.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I found new problem in textbox I can write only numeric chars and no alphabetical

Comment: That is because the issue is not related to the code you posted.

Comment: @TomaszCieśliński Then use `char.IsDigit` method instead and you can omit `ch < 128` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
private void OnlyAlphabetical(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Key < Key.A) || (e.Key > Key.Z))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
```